# Paypal REST-API Preapproved Payment Scenario

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I would like to implement this scenario via Paypal REST API

1. Client creates an Billing Agreement
2. Approves it and goes back to the our website
3. There he will fill out some data and press "Finish and pay"
4. Then a request via API will be done, so the payment will be processed.

I already created the agreement with `setAutoBillAmount("no")`.
So the client will not be charged immediatelly.
But i cannot find a call in the api docs
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#billing
where i can make a call to API to charge the client according to the Preapproved payment he made.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

thx

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pre approved payment in PayPal then I would recommend you to use suggest [Pre-approval API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/). You can use PayPal REST for [Recurring Billing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements) but it does not have a feature of Pre-approval yet.

Comment: Preapproval API would work, just its pretty limited: "The preapproved maximum total amount of all payments. It cannot exceed $2,000 USD or its equivalent in other currencies. Contact PayPal if you do not want to specify a maximum amount."